# Ants on my cat cause itching, how do I treat the bites?

Tags: cats, health, allergies

My cat has ants on him. What can I use on him to get rid of the ants that is safe for my cat? I have used body powder by rubbing it into his fir and that seems to stop him from scratching so much. I have already gotten rid of the ants that were in the house

**Edit**
He is an indoor cat. I had some ants get into my kitchen and shortly after that he started to scratch a lot. I no longer have ants in the house and I don't see any on him but now he keeps scratching the areas he had aggravated. He seems to be getting better but I hate that the itchy areas are making him miserable!

Comment: Related non-duplicate [Is there a way of getting rid of ants that's safe for my cats?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've gotten rid of the ants but your cat is still uncomfortable.

A few years ago we had an infestation of [Cheyletiella mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyletiella) that lasted for several months (our general vet couldn't see them in a microscopic skin scraping and it wasn't until he referred us to the veterinary dermatologist that it was diagnosed and treated).

One of the cats continued to overgroom even after the mites were gone. The vets explained to us that since she had been itchy for months, she irritated her skin causing it to remain itchy even after the mites were gone.

They suggested some anti-inflammatory treatments, which would suppress the itch feeling long enough for the skin to heal.

Unfortunately, our cat had had the mites so long that whenever the anti-inflammatory treatment was withdrawn she would start overgrooming again. It's not a good medication to be on long term, so we stopped treatment.